# Universal Links not working when default browser is Google Chrome in Outlook?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I open the mail link with default browser as Google Chrome in Outlook,
it's opening in browser. I am expecting the link to be opened in application.

Comment: you meant links in Outlook app is opening in browser? And you was expecting them to open in Outlook app itself?

Comment: Yes its opening in browser. I am expecting to open those link in my application. (Universal Links)

Answer (score 0):

The way outlook lets users choose chrome as the destination for links effectively disables the universal linking functionality provided by the system. Basically, outlook isn't opening the raw link, which would lead to your app, it is building a mobile chrome URI per chrome's [custom scheme](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links). Until iOS provides users a method to choose a different browsers, apps rolling their own solution will continue to break system expectations.